# How do you create a global object in visual c++ windows form

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I'm new to using Microsoft C++ Microsoft visual studio and I am trying to figure out how to create a global object in a windows forms so I could referenced it later in several functions.  The object type is called Picture.  Below is the code that I have so far.
Note: the name of the project is Testing_ver2

GUIInterface.h

```
#pragma once
namespace Testing_ver2 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for GUIInterface
/// </summary>
public ref class GUIInterface : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{


public:
    GUIInterface(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~GUIInterface()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;
protected: 

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;




    //This Is were I'm trying to implement the picture
    #include "Picture.h"

    Picture pic1;





     #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^ >(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(611, 201);
        this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
        this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 50);
        this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
        // 
        // GUIInterface
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(926, 546);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
        this->Name = L"GUIInterface";
        this->Text = L"GUIInterface";
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
    #pragma endregion



};
  }
```

Picture.h

```
 //This is used to hold the name of the picture, the path to it, and if it is picked in the viewer
    #include <string>

   class Picture
{   
public:
    Picture(){};  //default constructor

    Picture(std::string newName, std::string newPath, bool newPicked)
    {
        strName = newName;
        strPath = newPath;
        boolPicked = newPicked;
    }

    void setName(std::string newName)
    {
        strName = newName;
    }

    void setPath(std::string newPath)
    {
        strPath = newPath;
    }


    void setPicked(bool newPicked)
    {
        boolPicked = newPicked;
    }

    std::string getName()
    {
        return strName;
    }
    std::string getPath()
    {
        return strPath;
    }
    bool getPicked()
    {
        return boolPicked;
    }   

private:
    std::string strName;
    std::string strPath;
    bool boolPicked;
};
```

GUIInterface.cpp

```
#include "GUIInterface.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System ::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
void main(array<String^>^ arg) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Testing_ver2::GUIInterface form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

One of the current errors with the above code is that a member of a managed class cannot be of a non-managed class type this is caused on the line with "Picture pic1;" in the GUIInterface.h where I tried to create a object call pic1.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have no experience with managed C++, but one thing that seems kinda wrong here is your `#include "Picture.h"` inside a class, just before `Picture pic1;`. Not only it will paste `Picture` class definition there but also all contents of `string` header. Any includes should generally be outside any functions, classes, namespaces, etc. (unless you intentionally use them to "paste" something). Move that to the beginning of the file, just after `#pragma once`. You also seem to be missing include guard in `Picture.h`, should probably put `#pragma once` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I've changed it to put include above the class.  Now I just need to figure out the managed class error.